# initializing a 2 dimensional array of struct to zero (set the image to all black) in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization

I want to pass an image file to a function and make it all black.

Here is how I do it:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;

void black(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE black_image[height][width];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            black_image[i][j] = {0}; 
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = black_image[i][j]; 
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the same error message :

> ```
> expected expression before '{' token black_image[i][j] = {0};
>                                                          ^
> ```

Notice the pointer pointing to the curly bracket.

What have I done wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{0}` is a syntax used in initializations, when objects are defined. It does not form an expression that can be used in assignment statements.

For this, you can use a compound literal:

```
black_image[i][j] = (RGBTRIPLE) { 0, 0, 0 };
```

(This would also work as `(RGBTRIPLE) {0}`, but listing all three components shows the intent more clearly and may avoid a compiler warning.)

Since you are just using this to set `image` to black, you can eliminate `black_image` and the loop that initializes it and just set `image` directly to zero.

Comment: So the concept here is : I cannot assign an int '0' to a structure even though whats inside the structure is all int?

Comment: @heihei: You can neither assign `0` nor `{0}` to a structure. In an assignment, the right operand must be the same type as the left operand or implicitly convertible to it. `0` is an `int` and is not implicitly convertible to a structure; they are fundamentally different things. `{0}` is not an expression, so it cannot be an operand to an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to achieve the goal is:

```
void black(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    memset(image, 0, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE[height][width]));
}
```

Comment: I tried your method, but another error message shows up:  error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Comment: @heihei Because [VLAs can't be initialized](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p3). Instead of `RGBTRIPLE black_image[height][width] = { 0 };`, you could use: `RGBTRIPLE black_image[1][1] = { 0 };` and use it `image[i][j] = black_image[0][0];`).

Comment: @P.P good point. I can't see any reason to not memset here tbh

Comment: Thank you. @P.P  I just googled memset, I agree memset is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the good answers present, that fully address the problem posed by your question, and as a matter of simplification, as far as I can tell you have an extra unneeded loop and an extra unneded array, `RGBTRIPLE black_image[height][width]`.

Instead you can assing the black structure directly to `image` using a compound literal similar to what [@EricPostpischil posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63449292/6865932) but ditching the `black_image` array:

```
void black(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = (RGBTRIPLE){0, 0, 0}; //*
        }
    }
}
```

*If you want to be extra clear in the initialization you can use designated initializers:

```
image[i][j] = (RGBTRIPLE){.rgbtBlue = 0, .rgbtGreen = 0, .rgbtRed = 0};
```

---

Or create a single black structure and assign it to every element in the array in a loop:

```
void black(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE black_image = {0, 0, 0}; //**

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = black_image;
        }
    }
}
```

**Again, you can use designated initializers:

```
RGBTRIPLE black_image = {.rgbtBlue = 0, .rgbtGreen = 0, .rgbtRed = 0};
```

---

That said, these are alternatives to my prefered method, using `memset`, already mentioned in [@M.M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63449303/6865932).